# In a MongoDB document, using Node JS, how do I find the last item in an array, and insert a document into said item's sub-array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

MongoDB document structure

```js
{
  data:"data"
  arrayA:
  [
    {
      newData:"0",
      arrayB:["something","something"]
    },
    {
      newData:"1",
      arrayB:["something"]
    }
    
  ]
  
}
```

Using MongoDB Node JS, I want to find the last object in arrayA, and insert an object into said object's arrayB, how should I write the search query?

Comment: do you have a schema of this data structure ?

Comment: the code snippet in my question is the data structure I want to perform the operation on.

Comment: In node you can use mongoose to handle mongoDB, to interact with the DB you have to define a data schema

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose, this example is for a 'Product' Schema, you can read about mongoose Schemas here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

require mongoose, require your product model (schema), connect to your DB (this example called 'myDB'), and then call getProduct() function.

getProduct() will find a document with id: '5f323812akqwie123kasdid', set your data to update as you want, then call the updateProduct() function.

This function calls findByIdAndUpdate() and accept as arguments the product id to update, and the product updated.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product = require('./models/product.model');
const settings = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false };

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB", settings, (err) => {
    if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB connection succeeded.'); }
    else { console.log('Error in MongoDB connection : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    getProduct();
});


const getProduct = async () => {
    try {
        let product = await Product.findById("5f323812akqwie123kasdid");  // find 
        let dataToUpdate = {new: 'data'}; // your data to insert
        let lastItem = product.arrayA.pop() // remove last item of array and stores in a new variable      
        lastItem.arrayB = [dataToUpdate];  // set your data to arrayB property
        product.arrayA.push(lastItem); // push the updated item
        updateProduct(product._id, product);
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }  
}

const updateProduct = async (productId, update) => {        
    let productUpdated = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(productId, update, {new: true});
    console.log(productUpdated);
}
```